# How to write basic Error Handling when using AJAX JSON

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, error-handling

I'm not as clued up when it comes to back end development but have this small task of adding some error handling to the code that you see below. All I'm looking to do is display the potential error responses to the #results tag if they occur. It only needs to be something basic as the code itself should leave very little room for errors to occur anyway. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Let me know if you have any questions. Thanks for your help.

```
$('#hierarchyBtn').click(function() {

    $.ajax({
        url: "libs/php/getHierarchy.php",
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            geonameId: $('#selHieGeonameId').val(),
        },
        success: function(result) {

            console.log(JSON.stringify(result));

            if (result.status.name == "ok") {

                var names = result['data'].map(function(geoname){return geoname.toponymName}).join(", ");
                $('#results').text(names);

            }
        
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            // my error code
        }
    }); 

});
```

Comment: So what do you need is to display the error received from the server inside `#results` element?

Comment: Yes that's what I'm looking to achieve. I dont do any error handling work so need the bit of code that will handle any error. And also display the error to the #results tag.

Comment: The error handling depends on your goal, what kind of error handling do you need? In order to display the error in the `#results` tag you could something similar of what you did for the success case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the error you want the display is return by you for instance validation, you can access the erroMessage in the error() callback function but passing errors as parameter and access it with errors.message.

I will display a generic error for all error not related to validation and the validation error if any but, this depends but what you essentially need is to catch the errors that you thrown yourself and display a generic error for anything else, may not be ideal but works

```
error: function(error) {
    // my error code
    if(error.statusCode !== 412) {
      $('#results').text('A Generic error occured on the server')
    }
    // Validation error
    if (error.statusCode === '412') {
      $('#results').text(error.message);
      // or $('#results').text(error.errorName)
    }
}
```